# Chef Test Kitchen - Verifications

Tags: chef-infra, docker

There are a few gotchas I find trying to use test kitchen.
Hope this is the place

1. I try to run test kitchen inside a cookbook (using the single-repo-per-cookbook mentality), but then test kitchen fails to find the recipe and throws an error.
   When I place the kitchen.yml outside the cookbook directory, it works just fine.
   Can I somehow configure the base path for the kitchen to run from?
2. When I try to login to a node in the kitchen list, it asks me for a password for kitchen@localhost. in whatever tutorial I've seen, including the test kitchen own site, a password was not required.
3. Just wondering, although it's not fully related - I'm using the kitchen-docker driver, and I'm trying to have a base image in which chef is already installed. When I tried to do that manually it failed to ssh for some reason. Am I missing something?

Comment: I find this very hard to answer without any code of yours. Are you using Berkshelf? Maybe you look at one of Chef's cookbooks, like [build-essentials](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/build-essential) and copy over all the files from the top-level directory (resp. try to run `kitchen-test` there). Maybe support via IRC (#kitchenci) would better fit your needs.

Comment: @EladR, Maybe if you show us the .kitchen.yml, the structure of your project

Answer (score 0):

1. Thanks, the metadata was missing from the kitchen.yml file, so it didn't add the current cookbook.
2. For future reference - not sure if it's intended, but the password is "kitchen" for the user kitchen, and it can be set otherwise via driver config.
3. Probably something was wrong with the image. 
   Rebuilt and it worked perfect.
   checkout https://gist.github.com/iwfmp/9631593 for an easy build.
   Thanks:)